# Cropping and saving a portion of a scalable/zoomable Canvas View on Android

Tags: java, android, canvas

I developed a flowchart drawing app for android but I'm struggling with saving the drawing. I implemented a method to save the image but what this method does is basically printing out what's currently visible on the drawing surface. Since the surface is zoomable, what's visible on the screen at that moment is not always a good shot of the drawing. The app needs to make sure that all of the diagram is visible before saving the drawing.

Here are a few screenshots to further explain what's the problem.

Let's say a user drew a diagram such as this one:

[image]

Then you start inspecting the diagram. You zoom in and view all the diagram from top to bottom. After scrolling all the way down and making sure everything is right, you click on the save button at this moment:

[image]

Here's the .PNG file saved on your gallery:

[image]

In order to get a good shot of the diagram, you'd have to zoom out back and make sure that the diagram is placed in the middle of the canvas and all parts of it are visible. If you click on the save button at this point:

[image]

Here's the output, which is quite decent:

[image]

How can I get the full shot of the diagram without needing the user to do the work? Here's the code I wrote to save the image:

```
private void saveImage(){
    View content = drawingSurface;
    drawingSurface.prepareToSaveAsImage(true);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
    FileOutputStream ostream;
    File folder = new File(pathToFolder);
    if (!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File (pathToImage);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved" + pathToImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    drawingSurface.prepareToSaveAsImage(false);
}
```

Is there a way to get the whole Canvas and let the user select a portion of it?

DrawingSurface is a zoomable and scrollable surface.

Edit: Some methods to let you understand how scaling, zooming and scrolling works.

onDraw() method of the DrawingSurface:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    canvas.save();
    posX = Math.min(MAX_COORDINATE, Math.max(MIN_COORDINATE, posX));
    posY = Math.min(MAX_COORDINATE, Math.max(MIN_COORDINATE, posY));
    canvas.translate(posX, posY);
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    if (!hideLines){
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        for (int a = -10; a < 10; a++) {
            for (int b = -10; b < 10; b++) {
                canvas.drawLine(1000 * a, -10000, 1000 * a, 10000, paint);
                canvas.drawLine(-10000, 1000 * b, 10000, 1000 * b, paint);
            }
        }
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    for (Shape shape : shapes){
        shape.drawThis();
    }
    canvas.restore();
}
```

ScaleListener class to zoom-in/out when user pinches in or out:

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        if (selectedShape != null){
            float shapeScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            selectedShape.scale(shapeScaleFactor);
        } else {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 1.0f));
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

onTouch() method that detects scrolls:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){
    scaleGestureDetector.setQuickScaleEnabled(true);
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    final int action = event.getAction();

    float[] coords = new float[2];
    coords[0] = event.getX();
    coords[1] = event.getY();

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.set(getMatrix());

    matrix.preTranslate(posX, posY);
    matrix.preScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    matrix.invert(matrix);
    matrix.mapPoints(coords);

    final int x = Math.round(event.getX());
    final int y = Math.round(event.getY());

    cX = Math.round(coords[0]);
    cY = Math.round(coords[1]);

    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            isZooming = false;
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (scaleGestureDetector.isInProgress()){
                isZooming = true;
            } else if (!isZooming){
                final int dX = (x - lastX);
                final int dY = (y - lastY);
                if (selectedShape != null){
                    selectedShape.translate(Math.round(dX / scaleFactor), Math.round(dY / scaleFactor));
                } else {
                    posX += dX;
                    posY += dY;
                }
            }
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
            if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION && !scaleGestureDetector.isInProgress()){
                // Kullanıcı sadece dokundu. Nereye dokunduğuna bakılmalı.
                boolean touchedAShape = false;
                boolean addedTextOrLine = false;
                Shape lastShape;
                // Bir şekle dokunduysa o şekil seçili olmalı.
                for (Shape shape : shapes){
                    if (shape.contains(new Point(cX, cY))){
                        if (selectedShape != null){
                            addedTextOrLine = true;
                            if (selectedShape == shape){
                                getShapeTextInput(shape);
                            } else {
                                selectedShape.setLine(shape);
                            }
                        }
                        select(shape);
                        touchedAShape = true;
                    }
                }
                // Boş alana dokunuldu, önceden seçilmiş olan şekil artık seçili olmamalı.
                if ((!touchedAShape) || addedTextOrLine){
                    if (selectedShape != null) selectedShape.setSelect(false);
                    selectedShape = null;
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using a private class that extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener.

Comment: @pskink I edited the post and added the relevant methods.

Comment: getDrawingCache() returns a bitmap. onDraw() is a void method. How can I get a bitmap out of it?

Comment: I should create a new Canvas object inside the saveImage() method, override the onDraw method of the drawingSurface so that it returns a Bitmap object and pass the new Canvas object into this new method, and do what exactly inside that method? I'm sorry, but I can't quite understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I tried it, but it also creates a PNG file of what's currently on display on screen. In terms of final output, there was nothing new. I need to get the whole surface, regardless of which part of the diagram user was viewing or zoomin onto.

Comment: no, @pskink. but I'll look onto it. I had to upload the project to GitHub and Google Play Store today, since the presentations will take place tomorrow. So I had very limited time, definitely not enough to make such changes. But, I'll look onto it. Thank you for all the links and suggestions.